# Mod_rewrite rule for redirecting all requests within a subdirectory to the index of that subdirectory with path as variable

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have requests coming to my server already. I want to v2 out my API calls.

Currently I have the directory /v2/ and within that I have index.php

If I call /v2/index.php?path=users/123 I get the right data back from my database. All is well.

But to standardize my code, I want to redirect /v2/users/123 to /v2/index.php?path=users/123

I have mod_rewrite loaded in Apache, tested with phpinfo(). I am not sure whether I need to place my .htaccess within the v2 directory or at root. I do not have any .htaccess in root today, and I do not want to modify any calls not made to /v2/.

Any pointers where to place the .htaccess file and the right conditions to do so?

My current file is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v2/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I have put it in the /v2/.htaccess directory, but navigating ahead of /v2 yields 404 errors.

Thanks!

Comment: Where you place the .htaccess does not really matter - you just need to see to it that you match the correct relative URL path in each case. What do you mean by _“navigating ahead of /v2”_? Please give example URLs.

Comment: Turns out I needed to put the mod_rewrite rules in the httpd.conf file. That made it take effect. My ahead of v2, i mean /v2/some/path/ahead/of/it